# What Intent to start the Crashlytics/Fabric Beta app?

Tags: android, crashlytics-beta

Is there any way to start the Crashlytics/Fabric Beta app from the application? It is very desirable to open it to install a specific application, and a specific version.

Answer (score 0):

> What Intent to start the Crashlytics/Fabric Beta app?

you can use this:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.crash.air");

if (launchIntent != null) 
   startActivity(launchIntent); 
else 
   // beta app not found do nothing or something else
```

EDIT:

> Is there any way to start the Crashlytics/Fabric Beta app from the
>   application? It is very desirable to open it to install a specific
>   application, and a specific version.

I've figure it out how to open specific application. Hooray!

just add a string extra to your intent with the key "**pkgnme**"

> `launchIntent.putExtra("pkgnme", "com.awesomeapp.com")`

full code:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.crash.air");
launchIntent.putExtra("pkgnme", "com.awesomeapp.com")

if (launchIntent != null) 
   startActivity(launchIntent); 
else 
   // beta app not found do nothing or something else
```

about the:

> and a specific version.

I still haven't figure it out yet.